# Trouble understanding simplex automorphisms and preservation of subcomplexes.

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex

In [Evasiveness of Graph Properties and Topological Fixed-Point Theorems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0110) on page 23 the following is said:

> Consider the following two-dimensional complex $\Sigma$ in Figure
>   2.13, which consists of the sets $\{0, 1, 2\}$, $\{0, 2, 3\}$ and all of their proper non-empty subsets. If we let $f : \Sigma \to \Sigma$
>   be the simplicial automorphism that sends $\{1 \}$ to $\{3\}$ and
>   leaves $\{0\}$ and $\{2\}$ fixed, then $\Sigma^f$ is a subcomplex of
>   $\Sigma$. However, if we let $h : \Sigma \to \Sigma$ be the simplicial
>   automorphism which transposes $\{ 0 \}$ to $\{ 2 \}$ and leaves $\{ 1 \}$ and $\{ 3 \}$ fixed, then $\Sigma^h$ (? they say $\Delta^h$) is
>   not a subcomplex of $\Sigma$, since it contains $\{ 0, 2 \}$ but does
>   not contain the subset $\{ 0 \}$ and $\{ 2 \}$.

I would have guessed the other way around as switching $\{ 1 \}$ and $\{ 3 \}$ moves them to two different triangles, where as switching $\{ 0 \}$ and $\{ 2 \}$ preserves the triangles of every vertex. I'm not exactly sure how they are "removing" $\{ 0 \}$ and $\{ 2 \}$ as subsets.

Comment: What is the definition of $\Sigma^f$?

Comment: @LeeMosher: I believe it is the image of $f$ when applied to the simplex $\Sigma$ which is again a new simplex.

Comment: That does not sound right. $\Sigma$ is not a simplex, it is the entire simplicial complex. Is $\Sigma^f$ defined in that paper?

Comment: It says: $\Delta^G$ is the set of $G$ invariant simplices. So maybe $\Sigma^f$ is the set of $f$ invariant simplices?

Comment: Hmmm... Atm still not sure I understand but it is definitely a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the largest sets are $\{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ and $\{0, 2, 3 \}$. Thus, there is no $\{ 1, 3 \}$ as a proper subset however, there is a $\{ 0, 2 \}$. So: $h(\{0, 2 \}) = \{2, 0 \} = \{0, 2 \}$ and therefore $\{0, 2 \}$ is $h$-invariant but neither $\{ 2 \}$ nor $\{ 0 \}$ but for $\Sigma^h$ to be a simplex, it must contain $\{0\}$ and $\{2\}$. However, this is not an issue for $\Sigma^f$ as $\{1, 3\}$ is not even part of $\Sigma$.